# Unicode characters aren't loading properly from file

Tags: c++, c, unicode

I have a text file containing some characters including a few unicode characters. I have tried saving this file with the following encodings without solving the problem: UTF8, UTF8 without BOM, UCS2 BE and UCS2 LE. Here's the code for attempting to read the file line by line.

```
    std::wifstream infile("my_file.txt");
    wchar_t line[1024];
    while (infile.getline(line, sizeof(line))) { ... }
```

"line" has a value of garbage in place of unicode and normal where there's an ASCII character. It's values look like: L"ï»¿Normal text here" instead of L"€Normal text here"

I've tried other variations like:

```
    std::wifstream infile("my_file.txt");
    std::wstring line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)){ ... }
```

I've tried setting locale too. I'm on a Windows computer. How can I get unicode to work as desired? I'd prefer a format that works on all platfroms but at this stage I'll take anything.

Thanks.

Comment: In case you have not ***[seen this yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905235/unicode-file-writing-and-reading-in-c)***, it may also add some understanding to what you are doing.  ***[this also](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/376642/How-to-read-UNICODE-file-Cplusplus)***

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to *imbue* the input stream with the locale: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275260/1967396

```
typedef wchar_t ucs4_t;

std::locale old_locale;
std::locale utf8_locale(old_locale,new utf8_codecvt_facet<ucs4_t>);

...

std::wifstream input_file("data.utf8");
input_file.imbue(utf8_locale);
ucs4_t item = 0;
while (ifs >> item) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample data does *not* contain the expected Unicode character `€`.

The sample data provided "ï»¿Normal text here" is the 3-byte Byte-order-mark (BOM), indicating this and the following are UTF-8 encoded text "Normal text here".  So various methods of opening the file will not get "€Normal text here".

OP needs to create the file containing the desired "€Normal text here".

Windows offers non-standard options to the mode in `fopen()` such as `fopen("file.txt", "rccs=UNICODE")`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.90).aspx

Possibly even `fopen("file.txt", "r")` will work once the file does have the "€".